# How to read value from JSON object?

Tags: node-modules

I'm trying to read individual value from be json array object to display in the page. I have tried with below code but couldn't make it. Please advise what am i doing wrong here.

Apperciate your help.

Comment: `json["Reference"].length`

Comment: what do you mean by size?

Comment: `object.keys` should be `Object.keys`

Comment: please add the number you count.

Comment: I'm getting API response with about format.So after reference around 174 response from the server.I have verified through Online json viwer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of a *JavaScript* array via its property `length`. To access the array `Reference` in your object, you can use dot notation.

In combination, the following should do what you expect:

```
var obj = {
    "Reference": [
        {
            "name": "xxxxxxxx",
            "typeReference": {
                "articulation": 0,
                "locked": false,
                "createdBy": {
                    "userName": "System",
                },
                "lastModifiedBy": {
                    "userName": "System",
                },
                "lastModified": 1391084398660,
                "createdOn": 1391084398647,
                "isSystem": true
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
};

console.log(obj.Reference.length);
```

---

In case you are actually dealing with a JSON string, not a JavaScript object, you will need to parse it first via [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: http.request(options, function(res) {
   res.on('data', function (result) {
 
   console.log(res.Reference.length);

Comment: Why would you `JSON.stringify()` the result?

Comment: getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for console.log(obj.Reference.length);

Comment: That means that `res` does not have a property `Reference`. Are you sure that `res` contains your response?

Comment: yes , when i'm printing only res its showing all the JSON values.

Answer (score 0):

You get the length of an array by simply access the `length` attribute.
For example `[0,1,2,3].length === 4`.

If you just want to loop through the array, use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of a for loop. It's safer, cleaner, less hassle and you don't meed to know the `length`.

E.g.

```
[0,1,2,3].forEach(num => console.log(num))
```